# error on connecting to sql server with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I got this error:

> "This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server.
>   Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server
>   for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712"

and this one:

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified"

I already install the `ODBC Driver` like say in this message.
I added on my `php.ini` the extension and restart the `IIS` but still the error.

```
PHP version: 7.2.
Windows: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
Sql Server: 2012 express
```

My phpinfo
[PHPInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njLwB.png)

Someone can help me?

Code used (simple sqlsrv_connect)

```
$serverName = $this->host;
$connectionInfo["Database"] = $this->banco;
if ($this->user) $connectionInfo["UID"] = $this->user;
if ($this->pass) $connectionInfo["PWD"] = $this->pass;
if ($this->port) $serverName.=', '.$this->port;
$this->id_db = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Complete error message:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
       [0]=> string(5) "IMSSP" 
       ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "IMSSP" 
       [1]=> int(-49) 
       ["code"]=> int(-49) 
       [2]=> string(189) "This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712" 
       ["message"]=> string(189) "This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(6) { 
       [0]=> string(5) "IM002" 
       ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "IM002" 
       [1]=> int(0) 
       ["code"]=> int(0) 
       [2]=> string(91) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" 
       ["message"]=> string(91) "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" 
    } 
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that throw this error?

Comment: Did you define the ODBC connection through Windows? Just having the PHP drivers alone isn't enough. You also have to define the data source.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte its a simple sqlsrv_connect .. I edited the question with it.

Comment: @Dave How can I do it? I already have a .NET application in the same server using this same sql server and working fine.

Comment: Removed comment ... had my drivers and connections confused. Sorry!

Comment: Did you installed the extension php_sqlsrv also?

Comment: @VitorHallais - any luck? Did you find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Double check versions of drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) to be sure that they can work together. As it turned out - it is very important.

Check here if you use good version of `ODBC Drivers` to work with `PHP sqlsrv`.

For **PHP 7.2 and sqlsrv-5.8.1** you need to use **Microsoft ODBC 17**

further info how to install it is on MS docs site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=redhat18-install%2Credhat17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline)

For `RHEL`:

```bash
# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

# sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql17

# sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y mssql-tools
# echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# source ~/.bashrc

# sudo yum install -y unixODBC-devel
```